# Check directed graph for strong connectivity

Tags: graph-theory

I was wondering how many paths I would have to check in worst case in a directed graph with n nodes, so that I will find a path, which connects all nodes(in other words: so that I know for sure that the graph is strongly connected)

Answer (score 0):

There are linear-time algorithms based on depth-first-search which determine if a graph is strongly connected.

Comment: Yeah I also read about the algorithms, but I wondered I there is a closed formula for a given number of nodes